# How Can I Avoid a Circular Dependency in Firebase noSQL db in Swift?

Tags: swift, firebase, nosql

I've got a Recruiter class and a Position class.

```
class Recruiter: NSObject, Codable {
    var id: UUID
    var firstName: String
    var positions: [Position]
}

class Position: NSObject, Codable {
    var id: UUID
    var title: String
    var recruiter: Recruiter?
}
```

Any advice on how I can avoid a circular dependency? A recruiter object keeps references to the positions he/she is pitching, and a position object wants to know the recruiter associated with it. But, this is creating problems (an infinite loop -- circular dependency) when I try to input the data as a dictionary in a Firebase noSQL db.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So, the solution ended up being to add a reference to the recruiter's ID and to query the db for all recruiters, filtered by that ID. That way, the data stays separate. Easier than I thought!